# Set DateTime = To DateTime Of previous row on a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

Below is the code to a view created to pull delimited values from a table into new rows in a view.

This works well, but I can't figure out how to set the `TASDateTimeStart` column value to the previous row's `TASDateTimeEnd` column value where the id in both rows are the same

```
SELECT
    MallaghanApp.dbo.EmployeeClockIn.Id,
    Employee,
    JobType,
    EmployeeName,
    EmployeeNumber,
    value AS SerialNumber,
    CAST([TASDateTimeEnd] AS smalldatetime) [TASDateTimeEnd],
    CAST([TASDateTimeStart] AS smalldatetime) [TASDateTimeStart],
    ISNULL(((SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, TASDateTimeStart, TASDateTimeEnd)) / 
           ((SELECT LEN([SerialNo]) - LEN(REPLACE([SerialNo], ',', ''))) + 1)), (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, TASDateTimeStart, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) / ((SELECT LEN([SerialNo]) - LEN(REPLACE([SerialNo], ',', ''))) + 1)) AS MinutesClocked,
    Department,
    DepartmentNumber
FROM 
    EmployeeClockIn
CROSS APPLY 
    STRING_SPLIT([SerialNo], ',') 
LEFT JOIN 
    EmployeeInfo ON Employee = EmployeeCombinedInfo
```

[image]

I keep getting an error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value.This is not permitted when the subquery follows =,!=,<,<=,>,>= or when the subquery is used as an expression

Does anyone know the code needed here?

Comment: Why are you using subqueries at all here, when none have a `FROM`?

Comment: A tiny bit of formatting makes the code far more readable. And it seems you just reposted your previous question - which received no comments likely because of the same issues. Poor formatting, use of images, missing details, etc. For any sql question you should attempt to remove anything that is not relevant to the question - that likely includes many if not most of the columns in the query. No idea what `MallaghanApp.dbo.EmployeeClockIn.Id` is or how this is allowed in the query so it seems something is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) function to get this value:

```
SELECT eci.Id, 
        eci.TASDateTimeEnd,
        LAG(eci.TASDateTimeEnd) OVER (PARTITION BY eci.Id ORDER BY eci.TASDateTimeEnd) as PreviousTASDateTimeEnd
            
FROM EmployeeClockIn eci;
```